# Save Wikipedia text in English if German not available with $.getJSON in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I get the German text of a specific keyword (`var title`) and output it as html afterwards. This is working fine, but now I wanted to load the English text if the German text isn't available. This is also working fine with my code:

```
var length = 500;
var title = $('#title').attr('data-title');
var lang = 'de';
var url = 'https://' + lang + '.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query' +
    '&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=' + title + '&redirects=0';

$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
{
    q: "select * from json where url=\"" + url + "\"",
    format: "json"
},
function (data) {
    $.each(data.query.results.json.query.pages, function (key, val) {
        var text = val['extract'];
        console.log('lang-' + lang + '-text: ' + text);
        if (text) {
            text = text.replace('Siehe auch:', '');
        } else if (!text && lang != 'en') {
        var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query' +
        '&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=' + title + '&redirects=0';
        $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
            {
                q: "select * from json where url=\"" + url + "\"",
                format: "json"
            },
            function (data) {
                $.each(data.query.results.json.query.pages, function (key, val) {
                text = val['extract'];
                console.log('lang-en-text: ' + text);
                });
            });
        }
        console.log('lang-end-text: ' + text);

        if (text) {
            text = text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text;
            $('#text').html(text);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#text').html('<?= __('EMPTY'); ?>');
            }, 1000);
        }

        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

But after the second $.getJSON is closed, `text` is empty again. That means that

> console.log('lang-en-text: ' + text);

is working and outputs the correct English text in the console, but after closing the $.getJSON the variable `text` has no value anymore, what I can confirm with the output in the console:

> console.log('lang-end-text: ' + text);

How can I keep the value? Also is there a better way to check if the specific content I want to get (the text in this case) is available **BEFORE**, so I don't have to make two `$.getJSON` requests? Or is my way the right way to do it?

**EDIT: It's working now!**

I found the solution thanks to `moopet` and used `.done` and a new function called `.setText` to set the text. Maybe this helps others too as the question seems to get upvoted a lot. This is my code now:

```
var length = 500;
var title = $('#title').attr('data-title');
var lang = 'de';
var url = 'https://' + lang + '.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query' +
    '&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=' + title + '&redirects=0';

    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    {
        q: "select * from json where url=\"" + url + "\"",
        format: "json"
    },
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.query.results.json.query.pages, function (key, val) {
                var text = val['extract'];
                console.log('lang-' + lang + '-text: ' + text);
                if (text) {
                    text = text.replace('Siehe auch:', '');
                } else if (!text && lang != 'en') {
                var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query' +
                '&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=' + title + '&redirects=0';
                $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
                    {
                        q: "select * from json where url=\"" + url + "\"",
                        format: "json"
                    },
                    function (data) {
                        $.each(data.query.results.json.query.pages, function (key, val) {
                        text = val['extract'];
                        console.log('lang-en-text: ' + text);
                        });
                    }).done(function() {
                        setText(text);
                    });
                }
                console.log(data);
            });
        }).done(function() {
            setText(text);
        });

        function setText(text) {
            if (text) {
                text = text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text;
                $('#text').html(text);
            } else {
                $('#text').html('Text not available.');
            }
        }
```

Comment: There seems no error in code, as it's working in my console perfectly.

Comment: If you try this with html it won't work. Like I said, I get the text output in my console, but after the second getJSON the text variable is empty again at the part where I want to output my text with `$('#text').html(text);`. So `text` gets empty right after the second getJSON is closed.

Comment: @Fels This is just for me to check my console log output and at what position which value is assigned to `text` and it is not a variable. The variable `text` remains the same.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I already deleted my comment before you replied, because I realised I'm an idiot :)

Comment: you are assigning value to `text` variable in loop, so it may happen that last element is blank and you are getting value of `text` as empty. Best way is to use an array.

Comment: I'm just using a loop because the key seems to be a random number generated by Wikipedia and I don't know how to get the key-value-pair otherwise. So, even if it's just one entry, the loop is just one single iteration afaik. @shyammakwana.me

Comment: I checked it now. It is just one single iteration and then the loop ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running afoul of asynchronous javascript calls.

Your success callback:

```
function (data) {
    $.each(data.query.results.json.query.pages, function (key, val) {
        text = val['extract'];
        console.log('lang-en-text: ' + text);
    });
});
```

is called *asynchronously*. In other words, it's deferred until the HTTP request has finished.

Your

```
console.log('lang-end-text: ' + text);
```

is called immediately, before text is assigned, because that's how execution progresses. If you put the code for things you want to do with the text *inside* the callback function, you'll get the results you want.

Comment: Oh, right, so I should use a setTimeout to check if text has a value assigned to?

Comment: I just read your suggestion and edit. But if I put the code inside, it won't affect the case if the language is German, only if it's English (the `else if`-case).

Comment: Don't use setTimeout. You'll end up polling, which is wasteful, or you'll end up firing too early and missing the response. You can call another function from the callback, don't forget, or you can set both the callbacks the same function. The easiest would be to make a function called something along the lines of `doSomethingCoolWithText()` that takes a parameter of `text`, and invoke it from both your callbacks.

Comment: I just edited my question showing my solution using `.done` and also mentioned you. I think that's the right way? Thank you.